# Unable to start activity componentinfo?

Tags: android

The problem I have is that I cant start an activity.

Here's the code for the previous activity before starting the new activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        populateListView();
        registerClickCallback();
    }

    private void registerClickCallback() {
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewTop100);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent intent;
                switch(position)
                {
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextactivityActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextTvSeriesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Next100moviesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

(the activity I want to start is case 1/NextTvSeriesActivity)
and here's my code for the activity I want to start:

```
package com.example.its_time.mainmenu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.its_time.R;

public class NextTvSeriesActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.next_tv_series);

        pupulateListView();
        registerClickCallback();

    }

    private void registerClickCallback() {

ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewTop100);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent intent;
                switch(position)
                {
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(NextTvSeriesActivity.this,TvSeriesActiongenreActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(NextTvSeriesActivity.this,TvSeriesAnimationgenreActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

And here's the android manifest code:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.its_time.mainmenu.NextTvSeriesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_next_tv_series" >
        </activity>
```

com.example.its_time.mainmenu is the package namne.

I've checked the manifest file, the spelling is correct, the activities are in the same folder, what could possibly be wrong?

Here is the entire error:

```
12-20 19:43:53.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2071): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 19:43:53.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2071): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.its_time/com.example.its_time.mainmenu.NextTvSeriesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-20 19:43:53.037: E/AndroidRuntime(2071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at com.example.its_time.mainmenu.NextTvSeriesActivity.registerClickCallback(NextTvSeriesActivity.java:29)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at com.example.its_time.mainmenu.NextTvSeriesActivity.onCreate(NextTvSeriesActivity.java:21)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
12-20 19:59:15.371: E/AndroidRuntime(3182):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you paste in the whole exception you are getting ?

Comment: Look at the Java stack trace for your exception, and it will help point you to what is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: you have a NullPointerException. check line 29 in `NextTvSeriesActivity`

Comment: line 29 does not contain any reference to a layout, however line 27 does

Comment: yes, but the problem is that the variable "list" is null...this is why, we believe there is an issue with line 29; to ensure it is null, if you don't know how to use the debugger, you can just output a message if it is null or another message for the case when it is not null

Comment: the reference on line 27 was wrong, thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `next_tv_series` layout doesn't have a view with id `listViewTop100` and `findViewById()` returns null when called in `NextTvSeriesActivity.registerClickCallback()`. Calling a method (`setOnItemClickListener()`) on the null causes the exception.